# Python Numpy 'Invert' Boolean Mask Operation

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

When I have an array a and a boolean mask b, I can find the 'masked' vector c.

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 9])
b = np.array([True, False, True, True, False])

c = a[b]
```

Now suppose, it's the other way around. I have c and b and would like to arrive at d (below). What is the easiest way to do this?

```
c = np.array([1, 4, 7])
b = np.array([True, False, True, True, False])

d = np.array([1, 0, 4, 7, 0])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
d = np.zeros_like(b, dtype=c.dtype)
d[b] = c
```

Output: `array([1, 0, 4, 7, 0])`

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a 2 line solution to this. :-)

Comment: You can make it one line for fun: `(d:=np.zeros_like(b, dtype=c.dtype))[b] = c` (python ≥3.8) ;)